# How to set background color for all elements with the same class individually based on custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple elements with the class `.hours` and they all have a color attribute with a hex value like so: `<div class="hours" color="#FFFFFF">`.

How can I use jQuery to set the background color of all the elements individually so that the element over has the color `#FFFFFF` and the element `<div class="hours" color="#666666">` gets the background color `#666666`?

My attempt: `$('.hours').css('background-color', this.attr.color);`

Comment: make a `let`, and use that let inside ur .css

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Currently, your question is a bit unclear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Set the same color for all elements? Or a different color per element?

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific, sorry about that. Different color per element, based on the color attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` to refer to every element and it's `color` attribute

```js
$('.hours').each(function() {
  let elem = $(this);
  elem.css('background', elem.attr('color'));
});
```

```css
.hours {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hours" color="#FFFFFF"></div>
<div class="hours" color="#AAAAAA"></div>
<div class="hours" color="#444444"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Nick!

Comment: @TobiasT. no worries, glad to help :)

Comment: This is pretty ineficient, since you're calling `$(elem)` twice per iteration. I'm not going to discuss how this is 2 more times than needed, but, you should have a local variable like `var $elem = $(this);`, and use it twice.

Comment: You're welcome, but you forgot the `var`. The `var` is very important. Otherwise, you're creating a global variable.

Comment: You did. You edited around 30s after I've commented.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
$('.hours').each(function(){
   var t = $(this);   
    t.css('background-color', t.attr('color'));      
  });
})
```

Comment: This is pretty ineficient, since you're calling `$(this)` twice per iteration. I'm not going to discuss how this is 2 more times than needed, but, you should have a local variable like `var $elem = $(this);`, and use it twice. (this was copy-paste from the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS solution (for this jQuery is rather ineffective in my opinion...):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.hours').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute('color');
});
```

Comment: Notice that this is in "Candidate Recommendation" according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and shows a polyfill for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".hours").each(function(){
  let $this= $(this); 
  let color=$this.attr("color");
  $this.css("background-color", color);      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you asked, but the same can be achieved without JS, just with pure CSS and custom properties:

```
<div style="--color: green"></div>

div {
  --color: #e2001a; /* default color */
  background-color: var(--color);
  height: 40px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e1fwtcdz/1